# Lenovo Thinkpad Twist keyboard and touchpad problem

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo

I have ubuntu installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad Twist. The keyboard and touchpad never work unless I do a soft reboot,. I've tried changing settings in bios but not sure exactly what to change. What I have changed doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I get by fine with rebooting but it is still a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

After some serious looking, I found my solution. Apparently editing one line in grub did the trick. Me touchpad and keyboard work after a cold start on my Lenovo Thinkpad Twist.
Here are the directions I used

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=157115&p=813402&hilit=thinkpad%20twist%20touchpad#p813402

Cheers